# Changing html based on a variable value in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes

I am trying to display different sets of data based on a variable, without changing the route in meteor.js.

it looks like this:

```
<template name="somename">
{{#if form_submitted }}
display some data
{{else}}
display other data
{{/if}}
</template>
```

I am trying to do this with a helper:

```
Template.somename.helpers({
    form_submitted = false;
});
```

However, when I run this, I get an error.

Also, I would like the variable to change to true when the button is clicked (and then refresh to false after a certain amount of time)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a combination of template helpers and [reactive variables](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) for this:

```
Template.somename.onCreated( function() {
    Template.instance().isFormClicked = new ReactiveVar( false );
});

Template.somename.helpers({
  form_submitted: function () {
    return Template.instance().isFormClicked.get();
  }
});

Template.somename.events({
  'click button': function( event, template ) {
    template.isFormClicked.set( true );
    Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
      template.isFormClicked.set( false );
    }, 10000); // Reset after 10 seconds.
  };
});
```

Comment: where do I put the isFormClicked variable?

Comment: You're defining it in the onCreated method per my example.  You then can use the {{form_submitted}} helper you defined in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Helpers a functions that return a value.
In your specific case it would be:

```
Template.somename.helpers({
  form_submitted: function () {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Perhaps you could check the Meteor documentation about helpers http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers